# Linksys WUSB6400M wifi USB not working at Kubuntu

Tags: drivers

I'm using a Linksys WUSB6400M adapter and commend line show me this

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 13b1:0043 Linksys WUSB6400M
```

So, i have a windows and it works with it, but i want to work with Kubuntu too as well.

I tried with a lot of solution from google but no good result. my WiFi still not working on Kubuntu.

Update 1:

after i put this in terminal sudo ./install-driver.sh.

i got this output:

```
Running install-driver.sh version 20210917
Starting installation...
Copying source files to: /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.4
Copying 88x2bu.conf to: /etc/modprobe.d

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.4/source ->
                 /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.4

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j16 KVER=5.13.0-21-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/5.13.0-21-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu: 5.8.7.4 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-21-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.4/build/make.log for more information.
An error occurred. dkms build error = 10
Please report this error.
```

sorry for my English.

Best,

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The driver for your device is 88x2bu. Let’s build it.

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms build-essential
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu.git
cd 88x2bu
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

Reboot. Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Thanks, i still have error and not working. i write update 1 with output you can see above.

Comment: It suggests that you consult the log so please run: `cat /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.4/build/make.log` Paste the lengthy result here and give us th link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Just good a news, I reinstalled Ubuntu instead of Kubuntu and this Wireless drive works with it perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ chilli555 I ran the commands and I rebooted twice and it worked for the WUSB6300 on my repurposed HP Desktop, previously Win Vista! I have trouble recognizing the components and compatibility, but I am OCD, I will get it eventially. Thank you so much. I did not know to cd into where? and lots more I don't yet comprehend. Koodos to you guys>